# socket.io works on heroku but not on azure

Tags: azure, heroku, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I'm using git to deploy my application not FTP. Also I've set at client side:

```
var socket = io({transports:['websocket']});
```

Also in server

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
...
io.on('connection', function(socket) {    io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
    console.log('new connection on socket.io');
    socket.on('move', function(msg) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('move', msg);
    });
});
```

Websocket and 'Always On' is set on at azure and web.config does have:

But still emit to all sockets fails. I made simpler test version of my application. Deployed it again to heroku and had no problems.
Exact deployed application code can be seen here:

https://github.com/jmietola/testexpress

Answer (score 0):

Please disable perMessageDeflate header when using socket.io ..

var io = require('socket.io')(server,{
  perMessageDeflate :false
});